# Update value while inserting in a table using select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am inserting values in a temporary table using select statements which calls a TVF each i.e

```
Insert into #Temp(Rownumber, Percentage) select * from dbo.MatchFirstName(@FirstName) 
Insert into #Temp(Rownumber, Percentage) select * from dbo.MatchLastName(@LastName)
```

In `FunctionWeights` Table, I have `weights` column and `FunctionName` column that stores different function names.

`dbo.MatchFirstName(@FirstName)` and `dbo.MatchLastName(@lasname)` are the TVFs here. Now , I have a table called `FunctionWeights` that stores a constant value corresponding to these function names. Now, Before the value is inserted into `Temp` table in `Percentage` column, I want it to retrieve the constant value corresponding to the function name that `select` statement has and multiply it which percentage value which was retrieved from the function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the table:

```
insert  into #Temp
        (Rownumber, Percentage) 
select  mfn.Rownumber
,       mfn.ConstantValue * fw.Percentage
from    dbo.MatchFirstName(@FirstName) mfn
join    FunctionWeights fw 
on      mfn.FunctionName = fw.FunctionName
```

Comment: It did not multiply those values. Why is that?

Comment: Hard to tell without more information? Can you reproduce it on sqlfiddle.com?  You can use a normal table instead of the TVF.

Comment: :I do get correct values with select statement only, but Insert into #Temp is not working .What might be the issue?

Comment: now realize there is no common column to join these. The function that is called has its name in FunctionName column in TVF but how do I join these two based on that?

Comment: Something like `on fw.FunctionName = @FirstName` ?